# Xcode .storyboard run but nothing there

Tags: xcode, build, storyboard

I have built a file in Xcode using storyboards that connects together and displays the data I want. When I compile and run on the iOS simulator nothing appears apart from some empty cells and the title.

Comment: Update: Have found method, I opened the navigation controller and changed the initial view controller then back to the previous, that seemed to work. I here you can manually synthesise the storyboard as an array also.

Comment: is the 'Main Storyboard' set in the Targets of the project?

Comment: You have to set one of the viewControllers as initial view Controller. How are you initializing your UIViewControllers ?